# Why become moderator?

Tags: discussion, moderators, moderation

Why would anyone want to become moderator?
Which are the good reasons and which are the bad?

I'm convinced that most people on Meta knows the answers and want to share their knowledge.

Comment: When I originally entered the race 4 years ago I wasn't expecting to win. A large component of "why" was that there were N moderator positions available, and it was some hours before the end of the nomination period, and only N people were running. And I thought: well that's no fun. Let's make it at least N+1 candidates so the voting is meaningful.

Comment: @Willie Wong: it seems like a Catch-22. If you really don't want to be, you should be...

Comment: And to be honest: back then I had almost zero idea what moderatorship entails, and I wasn't even sure what kind of a community that I would like to see emerge out of the experiment that was Math.SE's early days. The tools we were given as moderators were also more primitive compared to now. So back then the agenda was muddy at best, the powers new and unknown, and everyone was just roughing it. I'm sure things are somewhat different now; unfortunately having been a moderator also means that I can't give you a virgin view on why someone right now would want to be one.

Comment: As a woman, I couldn't resist the temptation to have a diamond. (>‿◠)✌

Comment: All the kids wants the diamonds and the magical wands and the records @Anastasiya-Romanova $\left(\underset{\smile}{\overset{\circledcirc\circledcirc}{<\;\;}}\right)$

Comment: To want to be a mod is to partly be pathological in some way or another. I would say that in most ways, becoming a mod has made this site less enjoyable. More can be found in [an answer of mine](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9323/mse-and-meta-mse-as-seen-by-moderators?rq=1). On the other hand, it has kept my involvement level high, likely higher than it would have been if I were not a mod.

Comment: Respect is not a good reason. Very few people will be impressed by your "status," and many more will be critical or unfriendly just because you're The Man. Fun is not a good reason either, because as mixedmath points out, moderating is not really very fun. The only real reason to become a moderator is a desire to help MSE and its community that exceeds your desire to enjoy it as a user.  And because reading deleted comments is awesome.

Comment: @Alex, and being able to edit comments is even more awesome. ;)